# DrawerLayout при открытии/закрытии растет потребление памяти

Tags: java, android

Есть простое меню основанное на DrawerLayout, при вызове функций:

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerList);
```

растет потребление памяти при закрытии ~0.8 Mb при открытии ~0.16 Mb. Ни чего нового не добавляется. После нескольких раз использования, начинает лагать анимация. Посоветуйте куда копать. Заранее спасибо.

Решил проблему: она крылась в ListView в котором адаптер хавал память.

Comment: К бд обращаетесь?

Comment: Бд нет. Даже пустой (без данных) DrawerLayout хавает память при открытии/закрытии. (там опечатка выше 0.08 Mb).

Comment: Причем происходит это только на 4.4 (highscreen thor) на 4.1 (fly) все прекрасно... Может дело в железе, странно все это )

Comment: После System.gc() память возвращается?

Answer (score 1):

В Android device monitor (DDMS) и в последней android studio (1.3 beta) есть удобный allocation tracker, можно воспользоваться им. Запустить перед `closeDrawer()` и остановить после `openDrawer()` и посмотреть, где осела память.

Описание DDMS: [Using DDMS](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/debugging/ddms.html)